# Marshalling/Unmarshalling nulls in JAXB

Tags: java, null, jaxb

I have several hand-written Java classes in a REST Server that uses JAXB to marshall/unmarshall from XML (JAX-RS).

I have implemented a small class hierarchy borrowed from Scala: `Option<T>`, `Some<T>`, and `None<T>` and would like to use these in my model to distinguish missing values from `null` values in the XML.

For example, in the following XML, the value `phone_number` is missing and the corresponding Java model field should be set to `None`:

```
<person>
  <last_name>Jones</last_name>
  <first_name>Abe</first_name>
</person>

class Person {
  @XmlElement("last_name")
  Option<String> lastName;

  @XmlElement("first_name")
  Option<String> firstName;

  @XmlElement("phone_number")
  Option<String> phoneNumber;
}
```

whereas in the this XML message, the `phone_number` should be set to `new Some(null)`:

```
<person>
  <last_name>Jones</last_name>
  <first_name>Abe</first_name>
  <phone_number></phone_number>
</person>
```

I realize that with this scheme, I cannot distinguish a zero-length String from a null String.

I thought of using `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`, but I have many model classes and would rather use a "centralized" solution that works for all of the classes.

I believe that the correct solution involves using a `MessageBodyWriter` and `MessageBodyReader`, but I still want the built-in machinery to handle each of the classes; I'll handle the individual fields (including String and Date).

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't an XMlAdapter for the Option class together with nillable = true on the annotations suffice?

Comment: @forty-two: essentially, yes, but JAXB prefers to use [`xsi:nil`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_nil) for null elements instead of omitting them from the document.  I'm not sure how you can convince JAXB to completely exclude an element...

Comment: Note that a similar issue arises with empty collection vs. no collection at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250504/does-jaxws-client-make-difference-between-an-empty-collection-and-a-null-collect/2251675#2251675

Comment: @forty-two: The problem with using `XmlAdapter` is that I believe you have to annotate each field with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`. I have hundreds of fields in my server models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always set the `Person` class attributes to default values. 
If you default `PhoneNumber` to "None", saving it to XML will give you the following tag

```
 <phone_number>None</phone_number>
```

In any case, the PhoneNumber attribute will stay at "None" until you call a setter to set the phone number real value.

I hope this helps,